# Are primary forms the same things as primitive forms?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences

Which of these is better or worse than the other?  (Note that the pronoun *it* is here referring to some 3D object.)

1. You apply all the transformation data so that it won’t reset back to its **primitive** form.
2. You apply all the transformation data so that it won’t reset back to its **primary** form.

Are they both ok? Do they both mean exactly the same thing?  When should you use one but not the other — and vice versa?

Comment: @APPLE 1) You need to give more context (preceding sentence/paragraph) and 2) questions that are primarily about correctness are better handled over at [ell.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As adjectives the difference between primitive and primary is that primitive is of or pertaining to the beginning or origin, or to early times; original; primordial; primeval; first while primary is the first in a group or series. [Wikidiff: primary vs primitive](https://wikidiff.com/primary/primitive)

So here both can fit in the sentence. "Primary" might be more suited for this context, as "primitive" is usually associated with living things and their history.

Comment: Hence the "caveman" associations with _primitive_, but not _primary_. Though maybe the US ought to relabel its primary elections now.